# Initialize pass firebase value in react states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, toggle

I am working on a react home automation project, where in the first module, lights, I am storing the state of all of the home lights in a firebase database. I have been successful at creating a toggling function in my app, and it quickly writes to the database. No problems there. **My problem:** All of my toggle buttons are simple text that when clicked, changes color via a conditional `SCSS` class, but that is aside from the issue. Of course, I developed my toggling method independently of my database, so whenever the page is refreshed and components are re-rendered, All of the buttons are set to their initial states (all to off). What I need to do is figure out a way to sync the buttons with their corresponding values in `Firebase`. Of course I could set a state for each button index, but I thought that a wrapper toggle state would be a lot more efficient. Anyhow, I realized that the simple and best solution here would be to update the toggle `state` in the `componentDidMound()` method, so that the rest of the toggling can happen independent of the database and continue to display the correct value, but when I try to pass the data to my state, it throws an error saying that it cannot read the state of undefined. Same goes for `constructor()` as shown below. I already tested the data that `Firebase` was returning, and it printed `true`/`false` to the console when it should have, so how can I pass the data from `Firebase` to the state? Am I taking the wrong approach at initializing the buttons?
**Here is my component containing said issues:**

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import colors from "colors"

var config = {
  apiKey: "SSSSSSUUUUPPPPEEERRRRLLOONNGGKKKKEEEEYYYYYY!!!",
  authDomain: "something-someNumbers.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://something-someNumbers.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "something-someNumbers",
  storageBucket: "something.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1111111111"
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

class Cards extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="toolbar-spacer"/>
        <div id="wrapper-div">
          <Lights/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="card-container">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Lights extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Card>
        <div className="link-wrapper">
          {[
            {room: 'Office'},
            {room: 'Office Bathroom'},
            {room: 'Neekon Bedroom'},
            {room: 'Ryan Room'},
            {room: 'Homework Room'},
            {room: 'Living Room'},
            {room: 'Gallery'},
            {room: 'Guest Bathroom'},
            {room: 'Dining Room'},
            {room: 'Kitchen'},
            {room: 'Master Bedroom'},
            {room: 'Family Room'}
          ].map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <Room lumer={"s" + item.room.replace(" ", "")} key={i}>
                {item.room}
              </Room>
            )
          })}
        </div>
        <div id="card-title-footer" />
        <div className="link-wrapper">
          <Room lumer={"all"}>
            All Lights
          </Room>
        </div>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

class Room extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var room = this.props.lumer
    var staate;
    firebase.database()
    .ref()
    .child('/rooms/' + room)
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      staate = snapshot.val()
      console.log(staate)
    })
    const {isToggleOn} = staate
    this.state = { isToggleOn }
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    console.log(this.props.lumer + ': mounted!')
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
    var database = firebase.database()
    firebase.database().ref().child('/rooms/' + this.props.lumer).set(!this.state.isToggleOn);
    console.log(this.props.lumer + ": " + !this.state.isToggleOn)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <a onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.state.isToggleOn ? "toggle-text-on" : "toggle-text-off"}>
          {this.state.isToggleOn ? this.props.children + ': ON' : this.props.children + ': OFF'}
        </a>
    )
  }
}

export default Cards
```

**PS: My [github repo](https://github.com/flygy2003/Lights/blob/master/src/js/components/Cards.jsx) may provide context for some unclear references should there be any**

Any and all help will be appreciated and taken gladly. Thanks!

Comment: Btw I haven't Even begun the raspberry pi/relay integration so even if somehow you manage to edit the DB, nothing will happen

Comment: Please just keep this as a constructive community, not a harmful one!

Comment: Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! (via a developer friend of mine)

The issue was that it wasn't generating the right type of object to place in my state. In fact, I didn't even need to generate an object at all! All I needed to do was use `this.setState({})` inside the `firebase` callback 
(w/ an `() => {function}`) rather than traditional one), and simply pass my variable directly in the state as such:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var room = this.props.lumer
    var staate;
    firebase.database()
            .ref()
            .child('/rooms/' + room)
            .once('value')
            .then( (snapshot) => {
      state = snapshot.val()
      this.setState({
        isToggleOn: state
      })
    })
  }
```